# How can I preserve the original \x codes in strings with PHP?

Tags: php, utf-8

So I have a string with \x codes such as "\xA3" and printing these in UTF-8 encoding will print out the correct symbols such as £ in this case.

But how can I keep the original representation so that it just prints out \xA3 instead?

I've tried using `str_replace("\\x", "\\x", $xcodes)` and I've also tried `preg_replace('#\\\\x\w+#', '\\x', $xcodes)` but neither works.

Edit 1:
Please note the strings are from external sources so using single/double quotes in PHP doesn't make a difference. As soon as I print them out directly as they are, these characters are converted to symbols which is why I want to find a way to preserve the \x codes and see the raw presentation.

Edit 2:
The strings are coming from the user agent with codes such as \xA3\xA9 (yes, Shellshock exploit tests) so when I run the following:

```
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
// Prepare query with PDO, "insert into user_agents (values) values (:ua)"
// Define placeholder :ua as string $ua.
// Execute insert query.
```

MySQL will return an "invalid string value, \xA3\xA9" error. This is partly why I want to retain the hex code representation but also so that I can see the non-printable characters.

So instead of "Chrome 70.45[Non-printable characters]", I'd see "Chrome 70.45\Ax3\xA9".

Comment: Once a string literal in source code becomes a string value at compile/runtime, there is no way to know how it was written in the source code. You could generate source code for an equivalent string literal, though.

Comment: If "the strings are from external sources" then they don't get parsed like that. E.g. `php -r 'echo $argv[1];' -- 'asdf\xA3'` will output `asdf\xA3`. You'll need to provide a [mcve] to clarify what your problem is.

Comment: If you feel that you can't store text in your MySQL table, I suggest storing JSON instead of some arbitrary programming language's literal string format.JSON is a standard document format that many database systems and many programming environments support.